# ERROR 1136 (21S01): Column count doesn't match value count but am giving same number of values with same data type

Tags: mysql

I am inserting the same number of values as of my number of columns with correct data type but still, it is showing, column count does not match.

[All the columns are here in this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHOFD.jpg)

INSERT INTO map_city VALUES
    -> ('IN',744101,'marine jetty','andaman & nicobar islands','south andaman','portblair',11.6667,92.75,3,132,51,57,5,163,55,2770,4.76534296,2.057761733,5.884476534,61.92561093,8.605560944,763.0978608);
ERROR 1136 (21S01): Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

I have also tried, double quotes but still not working.

Comment: Please add table definition

Comment: I count 22 values in your statement but the table has 23 columns (which you should have shown in textual representation not as an image BTW)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try inserting values into columns with respect to their fields, like

```
INSERT INTO map_city (country_code, pin_code, place_name, ) VALUES ('IN',744101,'marine jetty');
```

Comment: Thank you @Aditya Thakur for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Please Try **NULL** value for the insert into the auto increment column (id), I think that will fix it.

OR

```
INSERT INTO tablename (col1,col2,col3) VALUES ('val1','val2','val3')
```